# Including height information when exporting images from SlantView 2

Tags: photogrammetry, altitude, agisoft-photoscan

I have a set of images that were collected with a slantrange multispectral sensor (S3P). To include the radiometric calibration information from the sensor, I use SlantView 2 (Ver. 2.17.4).

I will further process them on Agisoft Metashape.

After importing the images into SlantView, there is an export option. I select Agisoft and this is how the menu of options looks like:

[image: SlantView export options]

Then I set the filter has shown below:

[image: SlantView filter options]

Once the images have been exported; they are transferred to Metashape.

The problem I have is the images imported do not include any Altitude information.

[image: Imported images information]

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this problem?

By the way, when images are imported prior SlantView processing, they include altitude information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been to install an older version SlantView 2 (Ver. 2.15.0.2509).

There might be an option on the newest version that I am missing, but I doubt it. Also, the customer service is not the best. I tried many configurations and downgrading has been my solution.

'Write EXIF Tags' option exports the images with referencing information.

Options selected:
[image: Options selected]

Results after importing images to Agisoft:
[image: Images showing Altitude information]

Answer (score 0):

SlantView 2 appears to have been made legacy software due to the buyout of SlantView by Hiphen, are you still using SlantView 2 or have you moved to Hiphen's cloverfield solution now?

Regards,
Jonathan

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, thanks for your comment. I was not aware of the company transition. Will definetly give it a try. That being said, I am moving away from SlantRange and using MicaSense for all the upcoming seasons.